# Checking if user has submitted all dynamic forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I have a form in my HTML that gets cloned every time the user clicks the "#addOne" button. The form will be cloned a total of 3 times and each form has its own validation messages powered by the jQuery validation plugin. Once the user clicks the #addOne button to display the last form, it'll disappear and a final button ("#nextBtn") will appear that will finalize everything by checking if the user has submitted all forms successfully. If the user makes a change to any of the forms, they will be required to resubmit that specific form again. Every form has a page number, and using that page number the form will be updated in PHP. How do I make it so that the final button can know that all 3 forms have been submitted successfully and if any form isn't submitted, it won't advance the user? Here's my jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/avs9pejv/10/

**HTML**

```
<div class="article_properties">
                        <form class="article_properties_form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <p style="display: inline">Page Number</p>
                        <div style="background-color: #FF355E; padding: 5px; display: inline; margin-left: 5px">

                        <p style="display: inline" class="pageNumber"></p>
                        </div>
                        <textarea style="display: none" class="inputNumber" name="pageNumber"></textarea>
                        <p>Image</p>
                        <input style="padding: 0px" type="file" name="image">
                            <p>Subtitle</p>
                            <input type="text" name="subtitle">

                            <p>Text</p>
                            <textarea name="text" rows="4"></textarea>
                            <input id="properties_btn" type="submit" value="Submit/Update">
                            <hr style="border: 1px dotted lightgray; margin-bottom: 50px">
                        </form>



                    </div> <!--End of article properties div-->
                <div id="addOne"><p>+Add page</p></div>
        <div class="nextBtn" style="display: none"><p>Finalize</p></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".article_properties_form").validate({
        errorElement: 'div',
        rules: {
            image: {
                required: true,
                extension: "jpg,jpeg, png"
            },

            subtitle: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 25
            },
            text: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 35,
                maxlength: 275
            }
        },

        messages: {
            image: {
                required: "This page needs an image",
                extension: "You're only allowed to upload jpg or png images."
            },

            subtitle: {
                required: "You have to provide a subtitle for this page!",
                minlength: "Your subtitle must be at least 2 characters long",
                maxlength: "Your subtitle must be less than 25 characters long"
            },
            text: {
                required: "Please enter text for this page",
                minlength: "Your text must be at least 35 characters long",
                maxlength: "Your text must be less than 275 characters long"
            },
        },

        });

var numPages = 3;
$('.pageNumber').text(numPages);
$('.inputNumber').text(numPages);

$('#addOne').click(function()
                    {

                        numPages--;

                        if (numPages == 1)
                        {
                            var articlePropsTemplate = $('.article_properties_form:last').clone();           
                                $('.article_properties').append(articlePropsTemplate);                         
                                $('.pageNumber:last').text(numPages);
                                $('.inputNumber:last').text(numPages);
                                 articlePropsTemplate[0].reset();
                                 add_validation_for_forms();

                    articlePropsTemplate.validate().resetForm();
                                $('.nextBtn').fadeIn("slow");
                                $('#addOne').hide();
                        }

                        else
                        {
                                var articlePropsTemplate = $('.article_properties_form:last').clone();
                                $('.article_properties').append(articlePropsTemplate);
                                 articlePropsTemplate[0].reset();
                                $('.pageNumber:last').text(numPages);
                                $('.inputNumber:last').text(numPages);
                                add_validation_for_forms();
                                articlePropsTemplate.validate().resetForm();
                        }

                });

                function add_validation_for_forms(){
                $(".article_properties_form").each(function(){
                    $(this).validate({
                        errorElement: 'div',

        rules: {
            image: {
                required: true,
                extension: "jpg|jpeg|png"
            },

            subtitle: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 25
            },
            text: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 35,
                maxlength: 275
            }
        },

        messages: {
            image: {
                required: "This page needs an image",
                extension: "You're only allowed to upload jpg or png images."
            },

            subtitle: {
                required: "You have to provide a subtitle for this page!",
                minlength: "Your subtitle must be at least 2 characters long",
                maxlength: "Your subtitle must be less than 25 characters long"
            },
            text: {
                required: "Please enter text for this page",
                minlength: "Your text must be at least 35 characters long",
                maxlength: "Your text must be less than 275 characters long"
            },
        },
                    });
               });
              }


$('.nextBtn').click(function()
        {
            if ($(".article_properties_form").valid())
            {
                $('.article_properties').fadeOut("slow");
                $('.nextBtn').hide();
            }

            else
            {

            }
        });
```

Comment: **[Is this how your expected output should looks like](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/avs9pejv/12/)**?

Comment: I think you can take a two hidden fields..
in first hidden field you can put your total form count and in second hidden field you can put your total number of submitted forms..
and on final submission you can check both hidden fields are equal or not..
Hope this logic helps you .. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Almost! But it should also detect if the user has submitted the form. For example, what if the user corrects his mistakes, but does not submit one of the forms? Then the finalize button should not go to the next page. And if the user submits all the forms, but decides to change something in one of the forms, then they are required to submit the form again

Comment: from what i can tell you don't ajax so the page is refreshed after each submit so this brakes you dynamically added forms

Comment: @SunilKumar What if the user submits the forms, but decides to change one of the forms? The user will be required to submit the form again, but how do I do that?

Comment: @madalinivascu My project requires for the page to not be refreshed

Comment: @user2896120: You can do one thing..
- When user fill the first form you can hide the form and put `+1` in your hidden div.. and put the button `Edit Form` instead of the showing the full form..
- When the user clicks on edit from button you can put `-1` in your hidden field and show the filled form to user...

-When user submit form again we can again do `+1` in our hidden field..

Comment: That would will be a huge work.. What i would suggest is why not submit the `form` on finalize?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao How do I do that when each form will be submitted in PHP based on the page number?

Comment: `PHP`, not aware much of that. But yea, as I said you can achieve it but with some heavy work.. Have you heard of `Mutation Observers`? The logic would be too big and am afraid that can be answered here.. Give me 2 or 3 hrs.. I'll try to make u understand what I am thinking of.. In the mean time you can try your luck with `Mutation Observers`..

Comment: @SunilKumar That's a very good idea, but how do I put a button for that specific form that gets submitted? Let's say I wanted a button that will say "Edit Form + (the pageNumber)"

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Hmm, I don't know anything about mutation observers, but take your time, I would be very happy if this gets to work properly

Comment: @user2896120: You have to give unique id to button and find the parent div for hide.